# Force systemd to run ExecStop for failed unit

Tags: debian, systemd

Is there some way to force systemd to run the `ExecStop` command for a unit it believes is failed to start?

I am running on a Debian 10 system with the buster-backports wireguard package and the default systemd unit for wireguard (excerpt below).

While testing out the deployment a tunnel got started with systemd, but had an error in the Postup which resulted in tunnel being created in my case, but an exit code so that systemd things the tunnel is failed. The `wg show` clearly shows the tunnel did get created, it just didn't get all the routes/rules added correctly.

After correcting the PostUp, I wanted to a `systemctl restart wg-quick@wg0.service` but that gvis an error. Looking at the `systemctl restart wg-quick@wg0.service` output it shows `wg-quick: 'wg0' already exists`. Systemd seems to be acting as if the tunnel never got started in the first place. I also tried running `systemctl stop wg-quick@wg0.service`, but systemd does nothing because it seems to believe the unit failed to start and there is nothing to stop?

I know I can manually just do a `/usr/bin/wg-quick down wg0` and get the system to a state that will make systemd happy, but is there some way to convince systemd that it is confused about the state of a service and that it should run the damn ExecStop command no matter what it thinks the state is? I want systemd to to run the stop ExecStop, when I say stop! If there is some force option I could pass or something that would help, but I didn't see it in the docs.

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service

[Unit]
Description=WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for %I
...

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/wg-quick down %i
Environment=WG_ENDPOINT_RESOLUTION_RETRIES=infinity
...
```

Comment: First, just to clarify, your question seems to imply that there is a running service being managed by systemd, but `wg-quick` is just a script that sets up a tunnel that runs in kernel space (this situation is different than, for instance, openvpn). So, `systemctl restart` will just run the script again which will tell you that the interface `wg0` is already set up (nothing to do with systemd here). As for your question regarding `ExecStop`, please take a closer look at the [docs](https://sources.debian.org/src/systemd/246.4-1/man/systemd.service.xml/?hl=508:516#L508).